# Custom widget throws a NullPointerException on setRequestedViewSize

Tags: android

Good morning folks,

I'm working on an Android app and I've run into a bit of a problem. I have created a new class that extends View.  I have overridden the appropriate methods (the Constructor, onDraw, onMeasure) and am instantiating the View through the applications layout XML (which is called main.xml).

Within the source code of my app I have the following code:

```
public class CustomViewTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/* I *think* I need to setContentView before I actually can use any of the widgets on the form. */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);       
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// my new widget
newWidget s = (newWidget)findViewById(R.id.testWidget);
s.setRequestedViewSize(300);
   }

        });


    }
}
```

the problem here, is that s.setRequestedViewSize(300) throws a NullPointerException. Has anyone run into this before or can lend me some advice?

[EDIT]
The main.XML looks like this:

It returning null, but the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.testing.CustomViewTest02.newWidget
        android:id="@+id/testWidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks you!
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my widget, I had the correct constructor (Context context AttributeSet attr); HOWEVER - `super(context)` was being called - not `super(context, attr).` Once I fixed that, life was better.

Thanks for the info everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You have no view with the R.id.testWidget ID: it's not about nonstatic methods. Since `findViewById()` returns `null`, the next line throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do you reference your custom view inside your main.xml? @Pontus is right. There is no View being returned from the `findViewById()` method.

It would probably be better to get your reference to it in the `onCreate` method (call the constructor there if necessary) and then set it visible or add it to another view (whatever you are trying to do with it) once the button is clicked.

EDIT: Based on your XML above. Does your custom class implement a constructor that takes a Context and an AttributeSet? The constructor with the AttributeSet is the constructor that Android will call to create your class from the XML layout.

Comment: Yes, and it *displays* fine (I'm just painting that view a different color for the time being, until this issue is worked out). Only when I press the button do I get a force-close.

Comment: Instead of 'android:id=' , have you tried just 'id='? That's the only thing I see different from what you have and what the examples at the following link show: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html